# SalesPath - calculating cheapest path

Tags: recursion, tree

I've a Tree (representing a SalesPath), with each node having a cost.

Object is to calculate the smallest SalesPath i.e. sum of the cost of each Node
from the Root Node to the Leaf Node

Code below uses using recursion to solve the problem, the code works fine
(SalesPath (0-3-2-1-1) has cheapest path = 7 in the tree shown)

I'm having trouble visualizing the Stack, and articulating/explaining how Recursion is able to keep track of Cheapest Cost 
(i.e.  int cheapest = cheapestCost + rootNode.cost) between the multiple Branches

eg. from 0 - 5 - 4, the Cheapest Cost is 9
while from 0 - 3 -2 -1 -1, the Cheapest Cost is 7

Any can help provide simple explanation  on this ? [image: h]

Code :

```
 static class SalesPathRecursion{

            static int getCheapestCost_Recursion(Node rootNode){

                int cheapestCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                Node[] children = rootNode.children;

                int tempCost =0;

                if(children == null){
                    System.out.println(" Children == null, returning rootNode.cost => " + rootNode.cost);
                    return rootNode.cost;
                }else{
                    for(int i=0; i< children.length; i++){
                        tempCost = getCheapestCost_Recursion(children[i]);

                        if(tempCost < cheapestCost){
                            cheapestCost = tempCost;
                        }
                        System.out.println(" CheapestCost is " + cheapestCost);
                    }
                }

                int cheapest = cheapestCost + rootNode.cost;
                System.out.println(" Returning : rootNode.cost => " + rootNode.cost + " cheapest is => " + cheapest);

                return cheapest;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *classic* example of recursion!

The caller invokes the recursive function, passing in the root node and asking "what's the cheapest cost to a leaf?". The root node (0) at the base of the call tree responds, "I'm not sure yet. Hold on while I ask each of my children to see which one of them has the cheapest cost". However, none of the children have an answer to that question either just yet, so they ask each of their children the exact same question, and so on.

Eventually, a [leaf node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology_used_in_trees) (say, 4, from your example) is reached and says "I know! The cheapest cost from me to a leaf node is *my own value*, 4! I'm going to tell my parent." This is called the [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_case_(recursion)). The base case is the first function call so far that provides a definitive answer, in this case to a very small subproblem, information from which will be used to build the solution to the larger problem. The process of breaking down problems too large to solve at once into small, easily solvable problems is called [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm).

The parent of node 4, node 5, now knows that the cheapest cost from itself to a leaf (4, its only child) is `5 + 4 = 9` and tells its parent, the root node 0. The root node is now armed with a definite value from its leftmost child (the root-to-leaf path cost, 9, is cheaper than infinity, so it's stored as the best so far), but still needs to ask its other children for their costs, which it does. Eventually, all children will report their respective costs, with `0->3->2->1->1` proving cheapest.

The algorithm uses [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), exploring one branch completely before exploring anything else. In other words, `0->5->4` is completely explored before `0->3->2->1->1`.

---

#### Example 1

Consider a small example tree of nodes with unique costs:

```
        0
       / \
      4   1
     /  
    5
```

We expect `0->1` to be the cheapest path with cost of 1. Let's run the algorithm with verbose, conversational output on this tree. Whenever a recursive call is made, the prints are indented. Parentheses refer to a specific node. See if you can trace the execution:

```
(0), what's your min cost?
(0) says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...
(0) says: I'm asking (4) for its min cost...
      (4), what's your min cost?
      (4) says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...
      (4) says: I'm asking (5) for its min cost...
            (5), what's your min cost?
            (5) says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is 5
      (4) says: I got the cost 5 from (5), a new best!
      (4) says: I checked my children and I know my min cost is 9
(0) says: I got the cost 9 from (4), a new best!
(0) says: I'm asking (1) for its min cost...
      (1), what's your min cost?
      (1) says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is 1
(0) says: I got the cost 1 from (1), a new best!
(0) says: I checked my children and I know my min cost is 1
```

---

#### Example 2

Here's another, larger tree, again with unique nodes:

```
         0
       / | \
      4  1  7
     /  / \  
    5  6   2
            \
             3
```

We expect `0->1->2->3` to be the cheapest path with cost 6. Let's look at the verbose output. Try once more to trace the execution.

```
(0), what's your min cost?
(0) says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...
(0) says: I'm asking (4) for its min cost...
      (4), what's your min cost?
      (4) says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...
      (4) says: I'm asking (5) for its min cost...
            (5), what's your min cost?
            (5) says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is 5
      (4) says: I got the cost 5 from (5), a new best!
      (4) says: I checked my children and I know my min cost is 9
(0) says: I got the cost 9 from (4), a new best!
(0) says: I'm asking (1) for its min cost...
      (1), what's your min cost?
      (1) says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...
      (1) says: I'm asking (6) for its min cost...
            (6), what's your min cost?
            (6) says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is 6
      (1) says: I got the cost 6 from (6), a new best!
      (1) says: I'm asking (2) for its min cost...
            (2), what's your min cost?
            (2) says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...
            (2) says: I'm asking (3) for its min cost...
                  (3), what's your min cost?
                  (3) says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is 3
            (2) says: I got the cost 3 from (3), a new best!
            (2) says: I checked my children and I know my min cost is 5
      (1) says: I got the cost 5 from (2), a new best!
      (1) says: I checked my children and I know my min cost is 6
(0) says: I got the cost 6 from (1), a new best!
(0) says: I'm asking (7) for its min cost...
      (7), what's your min cost?
      (7) says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is 7
(0) says: I got the cost 7 from (7) but it's not the best
(0) says: I checked my children and I know my min cost is 6
```

Here's the code that produces the above output:

```
static void say(String message, int depth) {
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(message);
}

static int getCheapestCostRecursion(Node node, int depth) {
    say("(" + node.cost + "), what's your min cost?", depth);

    if (node.children.length == 0) {
        say(
            "(" + node.cost + 
            ") says: I'm a leaf! My min cost is " +
            node.cost, depth
        );
        return node.cost;
    }

    say(
        "(" + node.cost + 
        ") says: Hang on, I need to ask my children...",
        depth
    );

    int cheapestCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Node child : node.children) {
        say(
            "(" + node.cost + 
            ") says: I'm asking (" + child.cost + 
            ") for its min cost...", depth
        );

        int childCost = getCheapestCostRecursion(child, depth + 6);

        say(
            "(" + node.cost + 
            ") says: I got the cost " + childCost + 
            " from (" + child.cost + ")", depth
        );

        if (childCost < cheapestCost) {
            say(
                "(" + node.cost + 
                ") says: I got the cost " + childCost + 
                " from (" + child.cost + "), a new best",
                depth
            );
            cheapestCost = childCost;
        }
        else {
            say(
                "(" + node.cost + 
                ") says: I got the cost " + childCost + 
                " from (" + child.cost + 
                "), but it's not the best", depth
            );
        }
    }

    say(
        "(" + node.cost + 
        ") says: I checked my children and I know " +
        "my min cost is " + (cheapestCost + node.cost),
        depth
    );

    return cheapestCost + node.cost;
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/MemorableJoyfulQueries)

Comment: Thanks, that is a very helpful/detailed explanation .. however, one question - why did you use "depth" (intially 0, then depth + 6) to print out the comments ? is there any significance to that ?

Comment: Yup--that determines the indentation level you see in the output. Each call depth indents 6 spaces further, so you can easily visualize the call stack.